# Can I fully utilize HDR Infiniband network throughput between servers and NFS volume?

Tags: linux, nfs, cluster, infiniband

I'm working on a project building a CPU cluster, and those servers and NFS storage (not a parallel file system) are going to be connected through HDR InfiniBand cables. In this architecture, can I get proper storage I/O performance through the InfiniBand network, and does NFS support InfiniBand communication? Or should I build a 200G Ethernet network (not an IB network) fabric to write and read from storage? If possible, are there any things I should configure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a 1gbps, such that 1000 / 8 = 125 MB/sec maximum throughput, and I observe 112 MB/sec via `scp`  (about a 10% overhead hit) would you expect to see 100x going from 1gbps to 100gbps HDR infiniband, a 12500 MB/s copy speed, no.  The fastest I've seen is 1.0 GB/s over `scp` not 12.5 GB/s. I believe there are other limiting factors preventing *maximum* throughput in that manner.  However I can do multiple copies simultaneously and not see a speed drop off like on a conventional 1gbps switch.

in RHEL 7.9 my experience is that NFS as well as RDMA was not as refined and robust as in RHEL 8.8 (or later?).  The fastest single file copy via `rsync -P` that I've observed over NFS is 490 MB/s, with NFS `vers=4.2` and `proto=rdma`.  Typically the export using `async` allows faster transfer speeds than `sync` which I do see happen on a 1 gbps conventional network, but over 100gbs HDR I saw no difference between sync or async.  I suspect speeds will become more apparent as many nodes are actively talking versus just 2 nodes in my single file copy test case.